# Created exe file with Pyinstaller, changed directory and it tursn off immediately

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I work in small company, wrote small program to help people get data more comftorbale out of database in python. Used pyinstaller to create exe file. It worked. Almost. If exe file sits in dist folder it works but if I want to share with everyone else in company it doesn't. It just closes window immediately. How could I share that exe file with everybody that they could use it?

EDIT:
Found a solution. I haven't used: "--onefile' while creating that exe file. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

The instantly closing window (which I assume is a Console window of some sort) is likely caused by your application crashing.

You could call your .exe Python program via a Batch file like the following to get a better view of the thrown error message.

```
C:\foo\bar\yourProgramFromPyInstaller.exe
pause
```

Save the above as a `*.bat` file and execute it. Now, the console window should stay open until you close it.

When you got the error message, we can help you better.